# How does export default func()(func) works

Tags: javascript

It's a stupid question but I often see a syntax I don't understand but that I have to use.
Exemple :

```
function Navbar(style) {
 console.log(style);
}
export default injectSheet(style)(Navbar);
```

It seems to work like this : first execute first function and call second function passed in `()` with as arguments what first function returned.
Using something I don't understand not only feel wrong but is also a problem as I don't know when to use it/not to use it (do I need an transpiler for this feature, may I use it without `export` default, what are the pros cons, who that works) etc.

Comment: This is just JavaScript's normal function call syntax, used twice in a row: `a(b)(c)` calls `a` (passing `b` as an argument), then takes the return value (which must be a function) and calls that (passing `c` as an argument).

Comment: The `export default` statement simply exports the value of the expression `injectSheet(style)(Navbar)`. I can't tell what that expression means without looking at the definition of `injectSheet`.

Comment: Show us where `injectSheet` and `style` are declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no special syntax, it's just default-exporting an expression:

```
export default (injectSheet(style)(Navbar));
```

`injectSheet` is somewhere defined as a curried function that takes a function as its second parameter. It works exactly like you described.

Comment: Sorry I maybe should have put the function source code. It's right there : https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss/blob/master/src/index.js. Comments show : \@param {Jss} jss \@return {Function}. So it doesn't seem to take two parameters. By the way I never see this function in W3C, codeacademy, in any kind of tutorial etc. And I've been using JS for 3/4 years.

Comment: As I said, it is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) - it takes one parameter and returns another function which takes a second parameter.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I never heard of curried function before you, learning this new term has helped me finding [https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/](explanations I was looking for). So basically it's the fact that a curried function returns a second function that makes it working as the second function takes the parameter in the second parenthese. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually when you said that a curried function "takes a function as its second parameter" I was expecting something like this `func (firstArg, funcArg) {}`. But it's actually the returned function that takes the second parameter.

Comment: The link is broken, but I assume it's this one: https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/